# Isotope .ajax() not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I appreciate any help you can give me .

I commented I'm doing an infinite scroll through a foreach php and ajax to load the part of the page that I need, the only detail is that isotope use and when I try to load the new content in the isotope in the sucess function ajax , not load anything, the code above the call if the content loads correctly but not within the isotope.

This is the content of foreach

```
<ul class="projects_wrapper">
          <?php if(isset($feed['gallery']['data'])) { ?>
            <?php foreach($feed['gallery']['data'] as $k=>$v){ ?>
                    <li class="mix <?php echo strtolower($v['parent']['title']); ?>">
                        <div class="project_item">
                            <img class="project_item_img" src="<?php echo $v['logo']['src-s'];?>" alt="">
                            <div class="project_item_description">
                                <h3 class="project_item_title"><?php echo $v['title']; ?></h3>
                                <p><?php echo $v['description'];?></p>
                                <a class="button button_view button_project" href="/<?php echo $v['permalink'];?>">View More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="http://www.iec.ch/img/loading_sliders_2.gif" /></center></div>
      </ul>
```

This is the content for javascript

```
 var $isotope_container =  $('.projects_wrapper');
  var current = 2; 
  var catg = 'all';
  $(document).ready(function(){       
     setTimeout(function(){
        $isotope_container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.mix'
       });
     },1000);
      // bind filter button click
     $('.filter-link').on( 'click', function() {
         catg = $(this).data('filter');
         $( ".mix" ).filter(catg).css( "background-color", "red" );
      $('.filter-link').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        //use filterFn if matches value
        //filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
       $isotope_container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
      });
      /*$('.add_more').on('click',function(){
          var elems = getItemElement().add( getItemElement() ).add( getItemElement() );
          //console.log(elems);
          // append elements to container
          $isotope_container.append(elems).isotope('appended',elems);
      });*/
        $(window).scroll(function()
          {
              if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
              {
                  $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "/projects",
                    data: {pag: current, content_only: 1, category: catg},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                        {
                            //$(".projects_wrapper").append(data);
                            $(".projects_wrapper").isotope("appended",data);
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                            current++;
                            console.log('Me Ejecuto');
                        }else
                        {
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                            console.log('Termine');
                        }
                    }
                  });
              }
          }); 
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolve this for destroy isotope and reconstruct after like this:

```
function redo_isotope(){
      $isotope_container.isotope('destroy');
      $isotope_container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.mix'
        },1000);
  }

  var $isotope_container =  $('.projects_wrapper');
  var current = 2; 
  var catg = 'all';
  $(document).ready(function(){       
     setTimeout(function(){
        $isotope_container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.mix'
       });
     },1000);
      // bind filter button click
     $('.filter-link').on( 'click', function() {
         catg = $(this).data('filter');
         $( ".mix" ).filter(catg).css( "background-color", "red" );
      $('.filter-link').removeClass('selected');
       $(this).addClass('selected');
       var filterValue = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
        //use filterFn if matches value
        //filterValue = filterFns[ filterValue ] || filterValue;
       $isotope_container.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
      });
      /*$('.add_more').on('click',function(){
          var elems = getItemElement().add( getItemElement() ).add( getItemElement() );
          //console.log(elems);
          // append elements to container
          $isotope_container.append(elems).isotope('appended',elems);
      });*/
        $(window).scroll(function()
          {
              if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
              {
                  $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
                  $.ajax({
                    url: "/projects",
                    method: "get",
                    data: {pag: current, content_only: 1, category: catg},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data)
                        {   
                            $(".projects_wrapper").append(data);
                            redo_isotope();
                            //$(".projects_wrapper").append(data);

                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
                            current++;
                        }else
                        {
                            $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
                        }
                    }
                  });
              }
          }); 
    });
```